# Windows 10 doesn't detect my GPU, but my motherboard does

Tags: windows-10, drivers, motherboard, gpu

Under `Device Manager` my NVIDIA RTX 2060 Super is only listed as Other devices > PCI Device. I have 2 events for this.

```
Device PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1ADB&SUBSYS_C7541462&REV_A1\4&2283f625&0&0319 requires further installation.
```

and

```
Device PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1ADB&SUBSYS_C7541462&REV_A1\4&2283f625&0&0319 was configured.

Driver Name: null
Class Guid: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Driver Date: 
Driver Version: 
Driver Provider: 
Driver Section: 
Driver Rank: 0x0
Matching Device Id: 
Outranked Drivers: 
Device Updated: false
Parent Device: PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_1483&SUBSYS_14531022&REV_00\3&11583659&0&19
```

At 6:25:45 PM and 6:25:52 PM respectively.
Note, the 2nd message came at the same time I installed NVIDIA Geforce Experience. In my bios in the board explorer, my GPU shows up and appears to be connected, powered, and ok. HWMonitor by CPUID on Windows shows my RTX 2060 Super listed as a detected device, just not utilized. My 2 monitors are plugged into the GPU via display port and hdmi.

Q: Maybe the drivers on the CD disk for the mobo are different than what they provide on their website?

A: TBD (I can rip this. I'm using a MSI B550-A Pro)

Q: Install motherboard chipset and GPU drivers?

A: Yes, the motherboard drivers are installed. I can't install any relevant drivers for my 2060 Super because the drivers `aren't compatible with your version of Windows` or because no (NVIDIA) device was detected.

Q: Could it be not enough power?

A: This is my GPU taken from my old PC that I just put into my brand new PC I built. I'm using a 650W PSU with a AMD Ryzen 7 5800x and the 2060 Super. The GPU was working fine in the old system, and I was using it the day before I built this.

Q: Could it be the connections to the PSU?

A: No, I replugged all cables into the PSU and motherboard for CPU and the GPU.

Q: Try updating your OS, reinstalling, or reseting it?

A: I've tried, it doesn't help.

Q: Try updating to the latest bios version for your mobo?

A: I have, it fixed some other issues with my resolution, but not my GPU issues.

Q: Try taking out and putting it back in the PCI slot?

A: TBD

Q: Try putting the GPU back in your old system to at least narrow down the part that may need a RMA?

A: I have, it doesn't help.

Q: Try installing it in the 2nd PCI slot?

A: I have, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to NVIDIA customer support on 2021-04-04,

> RTX card require the windows build 1803 or higher

Since I had a really old win10 install, I actually could not update past a certain windows build, I had to download extra software from a MS forum https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10